# loop from end to start

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

At first, I use python 2 days and have more questions.
Below one from them.

I have a list (3297 items), i want find index of first item from end where value != 'nan'

Example: (index, value)

```
[0]  378.966
[1]  378.967
[2]  378.966
[3]  378.967
....
....
[3295]  777.436
[3296]  nan
[3297]  nan
```

if want found item with index - 3295

my code (from end to start, step by step)

```
    i = len(lasarr); #3297
    while (i >= 0):
            if not math.isnan(lasarr[i]):
                   method_end=i # i found !
                   break        # than exit from loop
            i=i-1 # next iteration
```

run and get error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./demo.py", line 37, in <module>
>     if not math.isnan(lasarr[i]):
> IndexError: index out of bounds
> ```

what i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting beyond the last item in the list. Consider

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> len(l)
3
>>> l[2]
'c'
```

List indices are numbered starting with `0`, so `l[3]` raises an `IndexError`.

```
i = len(lasarr)-1
```

fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

Is your code raising `IndexError`?  It should ;-)  `lasarr` has 3297 items, `lasarr[0]` through `lasarr[3296]` inclusive.  `lasarr[3297]` is **not** part of the list:  that's a position one beyond the end of the list.  Start your code like this instead:

```py
i = len(lasarr) - 1
```

Then `i` will index that last element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from the wrong position, array's start indexing from `0`, so where you have `i = len(lasarr) -1` is incorrect.

```
lasarr = [378.966, 378.967, 378.968, 378.969, nan]

for i in range(len(lasarr) - 1, -1,-1):
    if not math.isnan(lasarr[i]):
        break
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code and your solution is incorrect. Your method finds the first index where `nan` is found, **not** the last number from the end that is not a `nan` value.

Answer (score -1):

As your list is quite short, just filter it and take the last item (and its index):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'nan', 'c', 'nan']
lastindex = [x for x in enumerate (l) if x [1] != 'nan'] [-1] [0]
print (lastindex)
```